# How can I make Tomcat 9 accept requests that include a double slash?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, tomcat9

I have a web application deployed on a Tomcat 9 with the endpoint:

```
http://1.2.3.4/myapp/rest/endpoint
```

Some external application is connecting to this using a GET request, but is doing so with a double slash in the URL:

```
http://1.2.3.4//myapp/rest/endpoint
```

Tomcat returns 404 for this. However, with a single slash, the query succeeds with a 200. How can I allow Tomcat to accept such URLs (and map them to the correct endpoint)? I do not have control over the external application so I MUST be able to accept double slashes.

Comment: Is your application's context path empty or `/rest`?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks, I edited the question. The context path is not empty, it's "myapp"

Comment: Tomcat correctly normalizes URIs and forwards `//myapp/rest/endpoint` to the same servlet as `/myapp/rest/endpoint`. Please, add some details to your question on the nature of `/myapp/rest/endpoint`. What framework are you using? JAX-RS, Spring, etc.?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Yes we are using JAX. Thx

Comment: Jersey 2.x I presume? Can you provide the version number? It will be easier to find if it is a bug.